# Merging jumping pairs

Tags: list, recursion, racket

How do I recursively merge *jumping pairs* of elements of a list of lists? I need to have

`'((a b c) (e d f) (g h i))`

from

`'((a b) c (e d) f (g h) i)`

My attempt

```
(define (f lst)      
  (if (or (null? lst)            
          (null? (cdr lst))) 
      '()                                                          
      (cons (append (car lst) (list (cadr lst))) 
            (list (append (caddr lst) (cdddr lst))))))
```

works if I define

`(define listi '((a b) c (d e) f))`

from which I obtain

```
((a b c) (d e f))
```

by doing simply

```
(f listi)
```

but it does not work for longer lists. I know I need recursion but I don't know where to insert *f* again in the last sentence of my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler case that your algorithm fails: `(f '((1 2) 3))` should result in `'((1 2 3))`, but yours results in an error.

We will define some terms first:

1. An "element" is a regular element, like `1` or `'a`.
2. A "plain list" is simply a list of "element"s with no nested list.
   E.g., `'(1 2 3)` is a plain list. `'((1 2) 3)` is not a plain list.
   A "plain list" is either:

   - an `empty` list
   - a `cons` of an "element" and the next "plain list"
3. A "list of jumping pairs" is a list of even length where the odd index has a "plain list", and the even index has an element. E.g., `'((1) 2 (a) 4)` is a "list of jumping pairs". A "list of jumping pairs" is either:

   - an `empty` list
   - a `cons` of

     1. a "plain list"
     2. a `cons` of an "element" and the next "list of jumping pairs"

We are done with terminology. Before writing the function, let's start with some examples:

```
(f '())              equivalent to (f empty)

                     should output '()
                     equivalent to empty

(f '((1 2) 3))       equivalent to (f (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 empty)) 
                                            (cons 3 
                                                  empty)))

                     should output '((1 2 3))
                     equivalent to (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 empty)))
                                         empty)

(f '((1 2) 3 (4) a)) equivalent to (f (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 empty)) 
                                            (cons 3
                                                  (cons (cons 4 empty)
                                                        (cons 'a 
                                                              empty)))))

                     should output '((1 2 3) (4 a))
                     equivalent to (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 empty)))
                                         (cons (cons 4 (cons 'a empty))
                                               empty))
```

So, `f` is a function that consumes a "list of jumping pairs" and returns a list of "plain list".

Now we will write the function `f`:

```
(define (f lst)
  ???)
```

Note that the type of `lst` is a "list of jumping pairs", so we will perform a case analysis on it straightforwardly:

```
(define (f lst)      
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) ???]               ;; the empty list case

    [else         ???                ;; the cons case has
                  (first lst)        ;; the "plain list",
                  (first (rest lst)) ;; the "element", and
                  (rest (rest lst))  ;; the next "list of jumping pairs"
                  ???]))             ;; that are available for us to use
```

From the example:

```
(f '())              equivalent to (f empty)

                     should output '()
                     equivalent to empty
```

we know that the empty case should return an empty list, so let's fill in the hole accordingly:

```
(define (f lst)      
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]             ;; the empty list case

    [else         ???                ;; the cons case has
                  (first lst)        ;; the "plain list",
                  (first (rest lst)) ;; the "element", and
                  (rest (rest lst))  ;; the next "list of jumping pairs"
                  ???]))             ;; that are available for us to use
```

From the example:

```
(f '((1 2) 3))       equivalent to    (f (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 empty)) 
                                               (cons 3 
                                                     empty)))

                     should output '((1 2 3))
                     equivalent to (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 empty)))
                                         empty)
```

we know that we definitely want to put the "element" into the back of the "plain list" to obtain the resulting "plain list" that we want:

```
(define (f lst)      
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty] ;; the empty list case

    [else ;; the cons case has:
          ???

          ;; the resulting "plain list" that we want
          (append (first lst) (cons (first (rest lst)) empty))

          ;; the next "list of jumping pairs"
          (rest (rest lst))   

          ;; that are available for us to use
          ???]))
```

There's still the next "list of jumping pairs" left that we need to deal with, but we have a way to deal with it already: `f`!

```
(define (f lst)      
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty] ;; the empty list case

    [else ;; the cons case has:
          ???

          ;; the resulting "plain list" that we want
          (append (first lst) (cons (first (rest lst)) empty))

          ;; the list of "plain list"
          (f (rest (rest lst)))

          ;; that are available for us to use
          ???]))
```

And then we can return the answer:

```
(define (f lst)      
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty] ;; the empty list case

    [else ;; the cons case returns
          ;; the resulting list of "plain list" that we want
          (cons (append (first lst) (cons (first (rest lst)) empty))
                (f (rest (rest lst))))]))
```

Comment: Beautiful and detailed explanation. The program raises an error for malformed "jumping pairs list" like `(f '(x y z))` - not necessarily a bad thing, but maybe not what the OP wants. I provide an alternative in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Pattern matching](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) (using `match` below) is insanely useful for this kind of problem -

```scm
(define (f xs)
  (match xs
    ;; '((a b) c . rest)
    [(list (list a b) c rest ...)
     (cons (list a b c)
           (f rest))]
    ;; otherwise
    [_
     empty]))
```

`define/match` offers some syntax sugar for this common procedure style making things even nicer -

```scm
(define/match (f xs)
  [((list (list a b) c rest ...))
   (cons (list a b c)
         (f rest))]
  [(_)
   empty])
```

And a tail-recursive revision -

```scm
(define (f xs)
  (define/match (loop acc xs)
    [(acc (list (list a b) c rest ...))
     (loop (cons (list a b c) acc)
           rest)]
    [(acc _)
     acc])
  (reverse (loop empty xs)))
```

Output for each program is the same -

```scm
(f '((a b) c (e d) f (g h) i))
;; '((a b c) (e d f) (g h i))

(f '((a b) c))
;; '((a b c))

(f '((a b) c x y z))
;; '((a b c))

(f '(x y z))
;; '()

(f '())
;; '()
```

---

As an added bonus, this answer does not use the costly `append` operation

Answer (score 0):

There is no recursive case in your code so it will just work statically for a 4 element list. You need to support the following:

```
(f '()) ; ==> ()
(f '((a b c) d (e f g) h)) ; ==> (cons (append '(a b c) (list 'd)) (f '((e f g) h)))
```

Now this requires exactly even number of elements and that every odd element is a proper list. There is nothing wrong with that, but onw might want to ensure this by type checking or by adding code for what should happen when it isn't.